# Extracting all key value pairs from "XML Like" text

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a string

```
 value="test" 
 value3="343" 
_dff="323" 1212="2323".
```

This is similar to a property declaration for XML string.  I am trying to extract all property and value pairs.

```
 E.g value = test,
_dff = 323,
```

Probably value and field in two separate arrays?

In c#

Comment: What exactly does your XML look like?  Post a sample if possible.

Comment: Regex.Split(stringvalue, "\"([^\"]*)\"") -- worked for me...
thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<root " + yourString + "/>");

foreach(XmlAttribute att in doc.DocumentElement)
{
  // ... use att.Name & att.Value here
}
```

The drawback is it will not work if your string is not good xml. So you'll have to try if it really works for you. For example, "1212" is not a valid Xml attribute name...

Answer (score 0):

Is there always 1 space between the property and value combination? If so you can split the string by ' ', then loop through the results and split each string by '='. Take the results of that and put them in whatever construct you think would be best (List of string[], Hashtable, KeyValuePair string/string would all work)

```
 string test = "test=1 test2=2 test3=3";
 List<string[]> values = new List<string[]>();

 string[] split1 = test.Split(' ');

 foreach (string s in split1)
 {
      string[] split2 = s.Split('=');
      values.Add(new string[]{split2[0],split2[1]});
 }
```

Comment: I used a bit of regular expressions and got through with it.. thanks everyone.... first time using this and ppl actually replied.